# Multiline text in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, textview, eclipse-adt

I am in need of assistance. Basically, I am helping a friend to create an app on Eclipse ADT. I am modifying the "about" section and I am having trouble with textView.
Here is a picture that better explains my problem:

http://i.imgur.com/36QHHJD.png

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep text in resources, you should use \n for line breaks. Example from my app:

```
    <string name="about_text">HexWalk is a hex grid version of well known puzzle
    game NetWalk. In Netwalk type games, you are a network administrator,
    and someone has scrambled your network. Your job is to rotate all the
    pieces so that every computer is connected to the server by pipes and
    there are no lose ends in your network.
    \nNontouch controls:
    \ncursor movement - dpad, wasd
    \nturn hex clockwise - dpad center, enter
    \nturn hex counterclockwise - space
    \nzoom - volume up/down, +/-</string>
```